# Backup Windows Media Player playlists

Tags: music, windows-media-player, dropbox

I have playlists that I want to reuse it on multiple machine.
My music files are store on dropbox.com so the path seems to be the same on different machines (i.e. indeed I change Dropbox storing folder)

If you know how to do so; or another music players alternative to Windows Media Player can do the backup is lovely. Please help ^^

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your playlists are stored in **My Music\Playlists**. As long as you put the music in the same directory with the same structure you should be fine.